# How to remove the picture in android layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, android-relativelayout

I want to remove this top bar shown in the picture below: (Including the white background).

What I want is the following to appear on app launch:

If this is possible, please let me know including the instructions on how to do it.

Comment: I think you failed to add picture, try to upload it on google drive or anything else and share a link please

Comment: share the image link, we can add the image for you...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Manifest XML for the activity which you use to remove the TitleBar along with the image.

```
<activity 
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```